# What is the benefit of using `capture` and `concat` than just rendering a block directly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Looking at the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat) for `concat`, someone gives an example of how to use it below:

```
def block_to_partial(partial_name, options = {}, &block)
  options.merge!(:body => capture(&block))
  concat(render(:partial => partial_name, :locals => options), block.binding)
end
```

But couldn't you have just done this without the `concat`? It can just work with the `render` right?

Comment: If you need to write a view helper when your Rails app is using HAML, you're going to need `concat` since it's ERB there in the guts.  That was my experience anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` just renders a template - [concat](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat) writes it to the output buffer used in the response.

Takes this ERB for example:

```
<% render partial: 'foo/bar' %>
```

Since we are using `<% %>`the output of the Ruby code is just evaluated. Nothing is actually output.

```
<%= render partial: 'foo/bar' %>
```

And

```
<% concat(render(partial: 'foo/bar')) %>
```

Will both add the contents of the partial to the response body.

The real benefit of using `concat` is when you are creating helper methods that should write directly to the buffer.

[`capture`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) on the other hand is used to save the output of a block (a chunk of HTML) to a variable so that it can be used somewhere else in the view.

Comment: Note that API Dock is not the official rails docs and is usually badly out of date. I find it pretty annoying that it has a much better google ranking than the official docs.

Comment: wouldn't I be able to use yield instead of capture?

Comment: ^ They do completely different things. `yield` outputs a section of the layout or something captured with `content_for`. The difference here is that you can pass content as a variable with `capture` which makes it really useful if you are creating a helper which transforms or augments HTML for example.

Comment: why wouldn't `options.merge!(:body => yield(&block))` work?